# How to add title to the custom Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

How can i add title to this custom dialog??

[image]

I have tried like this

```
public void customDialog()
 {
  Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
  dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.string.app_name );
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_submit);
  TextView edit_model=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_model);
  edit_model.setText(android.os.Build.DEVICE);
  dialog.show();
 }//end of custom dialog function
```

I have tried to set title like this too..`dialog.setTitle("Enter Details");` but this too didn't yielded any result. So how can i set title to this custom dialog??

This is my dialog_submit.xml file used for the custom dialog.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
  <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          android:text="Name"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_name"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/txt_name"
          />
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_model"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
          android:text="Phone Model"
          />
<TextView android:id="@+id/edit_model"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/txt_model"
          />

<Button android:id="@+id/but_cancel"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/edit_model"
          android:text="Cancel"     
          />
<Button android:id="@+id/but_submit"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/edit_model"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/but_cancel"    
          android:text="Submit"     
          />                       
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 17):

Using some of your snippet:

```
public void customDialog() {
    Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_submit);
    dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
    dialog.show();
}
```

res/layout/custom_title.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a custom title"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try?

```
dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

Comment: I have mentioned it above aleady that dialog.setTitle("???") is not yeilding any result.

Comment: @Shijilal: Look again at Cristian's answer - he's setting the title with an int rather than a CharSequence. Make sure you try this method as well. It might not work but make sure you try both setTitle() options.

Comment: @McStretch I tried that..but its not working.dialog.SetTitle will work if i remove dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); If i remove this then there is a big gap between the title and the first view(ie.name),that's why i thought of going with FEATURE.CUSTOM_TITLE

Answer (score 3):

Using your layout definition and this piece of code:

> ```
> public void customDialog()
> {
>     Dialog dialog = new Dialog( this );
>     dialog.setContentView( R.layout.dialog_submit );
>     TextView edit_model = (TextView) dialog.findViewById( R.id.edit_model );
>     edit_model.setText( android.os.Build.DEVICE );
>     dialog.setTitle( "Enter Details" );
>     dialog.show( );
> }
> ```

I get this dialog:

[image]

So, you might want to try dialog.setTitle( "Enter Details" ) again.
I used the emulator running Android 2.1.

Comment: If you are not happy with the position/layout of the title, would it be an option to add the title as an TextView to your dialog layout?

Comment: yes i did this  too. But see the gap between "Enter Details" and "Name". Its huge, and i couldn't find any way to remove that gap, that's why  thought of using custom title feature

Answer (score 0):

What you might try, if you still need an answer to this, is an `AlertDialog.Builder` Object. In this Object you can also call the `setMessage("Title")` method, which will set the title in the `Dialog` you eventually create with this. Moreover, you can also specify a `positiveButton`, `neutralButton` and a `negativeButton` (let's say "Add", "Ok" and "Cancel" in that order, though you can specify your own text).

I believe the problem lies in that when you call `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this)` the `onCreateDialog(int id)` is called. But here's the catch: this method is called once and delivers a `Dialog` which is reused whenever you need a new `Dialog`. The `Dialog` however, can't be edited any more (as far as I know). Well maybe with the `onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)` method, but I am still trying to get that working myself. My point is, that after creation, you can't edit the User Interface on the Dialog anymore. So the way that does work is by Overriding the `onCreateDialog(int id)` in your code, creating an `AlertDialog.Builder` (or whatever you are basing your `Dialog` on: `ProgressDialog`/`AlertDialog`/etc.) and setting the title, layout and buttons here. After this, you can call the `create()` method, which will actually build the `Dialog` with your settings.

```
@Override
public dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    // Create the View to use in the Dialog.
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate the View you want to set as the layout.
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout,
                                         (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_parent_view);
    // Create Dialog Builder Object to create Dialog from.
    AlertDialog.Builder adBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Set the title to use.
    adBuilder.setMessage("Your title");
    // Add only a positive button.
    adBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            // Handle click on positive button here.
        }
    };
    // Set the layout which you want to use (inflated at the beginning).
    adBuilder.setLayout(layout);
    // After you've set all the options you want to set, call this method.
    AlertDialog dialog = adBuilder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

This will create a `Dialog` with the title set to "Your Title", which uses the layout you specified, and has one button with the text "Add". Note that the main difference between positive, neutral and negative buttons is that their layout on the `Dialog` is changed accordingly (positive = left, neutral = middle and negative = right).

For more information I would advise you to see the documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an `AlertDialog` if you have 3 or less buttons?

My AlertDialog looks like this:

[image]

My java code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_filter, null);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .create();
alertDialog.setTitle("AlertDialog title");
alertDialog.setMessage("AlertDialog message");
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
alertDialog.show();
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/filter_array"
        android:prompt="@string/filter_prompt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Simple yet does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but my solution is using an relative layout within the main relative layout. That way you can create your own title. It doesn't see a top TextView as a title if you use it that way:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:padding="10dp"
      >
 <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout_root"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#FFF"
      android:text="Name"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      />
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_name"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/txt_name"
      />
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_model"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#FFF"
      android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
      android:text="Phone Model"
      />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/edit_model"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/txt_model"
      />

 <Button android:id="@+id/but_cancel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/edit_model"
      android:text="Cancel"     
      />
 <Button android:id="@+id/but_submit"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/edit_model"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/but_cancel"    
      android:text="Submit"     
      />   
 </RelativeLayout>                    
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this line in to hide built-in title from dialog

> dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

and add **textView in your layout file**.