# Dialog.setTitle not showing a title

Tags: android, customdialog

I am trying to add a custom title to my Dialog, however whenever I run my application it doesn't show a title.

My code for creating the dialog is

```
 final Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(this);
 passwordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.admin_password_dialog);
 passwordDialog.setTitle("Enter An Administrative Password");
 passwordDialog.show();
```

And my layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_confirmPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_adminPassword"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/confirmPassword"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_adminPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

And here is what I am getting

[image: Here is what I am getting]

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852573/how-to-add-title-to-the-custom-dialog might give you a workaround

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you should define your style like this:

```
 <style name="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

and then pass this style to the constructor of the Dialog

```
final Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.Dialog);
```

Comment: That's called a solution, suggesting to use `AlertDialogue` instead of dialogue is not the solution, it may be a work around...

Comment: Why does Android development make me want to bang my head against a desk.

Comment: @Raafat Alhoumaidy After applying this the dialog background become black with title color as white, Why so??

Answer (score 9):

Like the other answer, but more concise

```
final AlertDialog diag = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Enter An Administrative Password")
        .setView(R.layout.admin_password_dialog)
        .create();

diag.show();

Button diagButton = (Button) diag.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirmPassword);
diagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // handle button click
        EditText input = (EditText) diag.findViewById(R.id.edit_adminPassword);
        String s = input.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: @RyanNewman - You could use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. If you look at my answer, it is also more inclusive, like how to get the Button and EditText from the dialog

Comment: When I try adding the onClickLIstener I'm getting a null object refernce. Do you know why?

Comment: Well, findViewById does return null if it can't find that id. I didn't test this, honestly, but I assumed it would work because of the `setView`

Comment: @RyanNewman - Apparently, you have to call `show()` first, I made the edit... that isn't very intuitive... :/

Comment: Perfect that worked perfectly for my current version of Android. I'm getting a warning on setView that it won't work on older than 5.0 (API 20) but that is something I am currently looking into

Comment: Like the other guy said, that method should be supported since API 1. I think Android Studio is confused. Mostly, you can safely ignore the warnings until they are actually a large problem.

Comment: If you are using `import android.app.AlertDialog;` instead of the support library version I mentioned, I would believe that is where the warning exists.

Comment: When I put it up on a 4.4.4 simulator it crashes which I'm not sure why

Comment: I was confused on what you meant by the support library. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: In gradle, you can add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`, but as long as it works, that's good

Answer (score 5):

You can try this method as well and get different view styles based upon theme used.

```
<style name="FilterDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

In Dialog constructor

```
  public FilterDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.FilterDialogTheme);
    }
```

Use `@style/Theme.Appcompat.Light.Dialog` for your project.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `AlertDialog.Builder` instead of just creating a `Dialog`:

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setView(R.layout.admin_password_dialog);
builder.setTitle("Enter An Administrative Password");

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) for the Android Developers Guide on Dialogs.

Comment: I wasn't sure if reassigning the builder for the `set` methods was necessary, so I made my own answer, just in case :)

Comment: This works perfectly for my device, but I'm getting a warning this won't work for phones lower than Lollipop. My current minimum API Level is 16, is this going to work on devices below lollipop?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you get that warning... AlertDialog has been added in API Level 1 (according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView%28android.view.View%29)) and the used methods should also be there since API Level 1

Comment: and I'm absolutely, positively sure I used that in many older projects... strange

Comment: Yeah I threw it up on a 4.4.4 emulator and I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.setView`

Comment: I figured it out. I added the layout into the default constructor `new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.layout.admin_password_dialog)` and it works now. Thank you for your help

Comment: @RyanNewman - Looked at the wrong doc the first time. Should be an `R.style` [theme resource for that second param](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Comment: I actually take that back. When I added the layout into the constructor it takes up the full screen without my custom layout